# Fluent-bit - Splitting json log into structured fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am trying to find a way in Fluent-bit config to tell/enforce ES to store plain json formatted logs (*the **log** bit below that comes from docker stdout/stderror*) in structured way - please see image at the bottom for better explanation. For example, apart from (or along with) storing the log as a plain json entry under `log` field, I would like to store each property individually as shown in **red**.

The documentation for Filters and Parsers are really poor and not clear. On top of that the `forward` input doesn't have a "parser" option. I tried `json/docker/regex` parsers but no luck. My regex is [here](https://rubular.com/r/o5nZZU2z0rjPWn) if I have to use regex. Currently using ES (7.1), Fluent-bit (1.1.3) and Kibana (7.1) - not Kubernetes.

If anyone can direct me to an example or give one I would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
{
  "_index": "hello",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "T631e2sBChSKEuJw-HO4",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2019-06-21T21:34:02.000Z",
    "tag": "php",
    "container_id": "53154cf4d4e8d7ecf31bdb6bc4a25fdf2f37156edc6b859ba0ddfa9c0ab1715b",
    "container_name": "/hello_php_1",
    "source": "stderr",
    "log": "{\"time_local\":\"2019-06-21T21:34:02+0000\",\"client_ip\":\"-\",\"remote_addr\":\"192.168.192.3\",\"remote_user\":\"\",\"request\":\"GET / HTTP/1.1\",\"status\":\"200\",\"body_bytes_sent\":\"0\",\"request_time\":\"0.001\",\"http_referrer\":\"-\",\"http_user_agent\":\"curl/7.38.0\",\"request_id\":\"91835d61520d289952b7e9b8f658e64f\"}"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-06-21T21:34:02.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1561152842000
  ]
}
```

Thanks

**conf**

```sh
[SERVICE]
    Flush        5
    Daemon       Off
    Log_Level    debug
    Parsers_File parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name   forward
    Listen 0.0.0.0
    Port   24224

[OUTPUT]
    Name  es
    Match hello_*
    Host  elasticsearch
    Port  9200
    Index hello
    Type  logs
    Include_Tag_Key On
    Tag_Key tag
```

[image: ssss]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution is as follows.

```
[SERVICE]
    Flush        5
    Daemon       Off
    Log_Level    debug
    Parsers_File parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name         forward
    storage.type filesystem
    Listen       my_fluent_bit_service
    Port         24224

[FILTER]
    Name         parser
    Parser       docker
    Match        hello_*
    Key_Name     log
    Reserve_Data On
    Preserve_Key On

[OUTPUT]
    Name            es
    Host            my_elasticsearch_service
    Port            9200
    Match           hello_*
    Index           hello
    Type            logs
    Include_Tag_Key On
    Tag_Key         tag
```

```
[PARSER]
    Name         docker
    Format       json
    Time_Key     time
    Time_Format  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
    Time_Keep    On
    # Command      |  Decoder | Field | Optional Action
    # =============|==================|=================
    Decode_Field_As   escaped_utf8    log    do_next
    Decode_Field_As   json       log
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. The documentation is simply horrendous. One question: how is your `log` entry ultimately decoded? I get a line of key=value (such as `name=john age=27 city=paris`) and not a decoded structure (it is not a JSON string aymore, but not a structure visible by Kibana either)

Comment: Not sure if I understand what exactly you mean but my application logs are in JSON format by default. So your example would be `{"name":"john","age":"27","city":"paris"}` if it was my application. Afterwards this whole string would also look same in Kibana under `log` key as shown above in the image. I hope it helps. Also have a look at [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/rel5/using-fluent-bit-to-forward-docker-php-fpm-and-nginx-logs-to-elasticsearch) for much detailed example.

Comment: Sorry for not having been clear. I used to have `{"name":"john","age":"27","city":"paris"}` as the `message` entry in my log, displayed as such by Kibana. I was hoping that this entry can be decoded by Fluent Bit so that it goes to Elasticsearch as a true JSON entry, and so that I have the keys `name`, `age`and `city` as fields (at the same level as your entre `tag`or `source`.

Comment: (cont'd) What I have is still a `message` entry which is now `name=john age=27 city=paris` (instead of the JSON string representation before). I was wondering if this is the expected behaviour (which makes the decoder useless because I cannot search on key `city` for instance)

Comment: In other words, the entry under `message` has been rewritten from the string `{"name":"john","age":"27","city":"paris"}` into the string `name=john age=27 city=paris`, which is not the parsing I expected (→ to "explode" the JSON string into actual fields for Kibana)

Comment: Also thanks for your link - I see that what the author got at the very end is exactly what I am looking for - so this must be something on my side. I get a JSON → key/value pairs translation instead of the expected parsing.

Comment: If your app log is an JSON formatted string, you should have a `log` field in Kibana that contains the original JSON **as is**. On top of that, you should also have `name`, `age` and `city` as individual fields. All these depend on the parser so if you used the very last parser in that blog (_same as the one I have above_), it should work. Pay attention to filter bit in `fluent-bit.conf` file as well.

Comment: Hey @BentCoder, What if i has to parse log field which is not a json its a String at one line like "2020-07-11 10:55:38,022 - INFO     kv : 1" if they are strictly aligned, 0 if not then what changes do we need to do on filter side

Comment: @AmanKumarSoni, you need to use `format regex` (with the named capture feature) for that: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/parsers/regular-expression

Comment: How to name `Key_Data` if the key is nested. In my case it's `log_processed['message']`. And I tried: `log_processed['message']`, `log_processed.message` and `log_processed_message` none of these work.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for a more general use case when using Firelens with the [`aws-for-fluent-bit`](https://github.com/aws/aws-for-fluent-bit) image, where the message end up as a top-level key `log` like here:

```json
{
    "log": "{\"time_local\":\"2019-06-21T21:34:02+0000\",\"client_ip\":\"-\",\"remote_addr\":\"192.168.192.3\",\"remote_user\":\"\",\"request\":\"GET / HTTP/1.1\",\"status\":\"200\",\"body_bytes_sent\":\"0\",\"request_time\":\"0.001\",\"http_referrer\":\"-\",\"http_user_agent\":\"curl/7.38.0\",\"request_id\":\"91835d61520d289952b7e9b8f658e64f\"}"
}
```

Following [this official AWS example](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-examples/blob/mainline/examples/fluent-bit/parse-json/README.md), notice that a [JSON parser already exists in the image](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-examples/blob/mainline/examples/fluent-bit/parse-json/extra.conf), which can be used like so:

```json
"firelensConfiguration": {
    "type": "fluentbit",
    "options": {
        "config-file-type": "file",
        "config-file-value": "/fluent-bit/configs/parse-json.conf"
    }
}
```

**OR** it can be called with an environment variable:

```json
"environment": [
    {
        "name": "aws_fluent_bit_init_file_1",
        "value": "/fluent-bit/configs/parse-json.conf"
    }
]
```

---

Result:

```json
{
    "time_local": "2019-06-21T21:34:02+0000",
    "client_ip": "-",
    "remote_addr": "192.168.192.3",
    "remote_user": "",
    "request": "GET / HTTP/1.1",
    "status": "200",
    "body_bytes_sent": "0",
    "request_time": "0.001",
    "http_referrer": "-",
    "http_user_agent": "curl/7.38.0",
    "request_id": "91835d61520d289952b7e9b8f658e64f"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a log file with JSON objects separated by newlines, I was able to get it working with this config. No filters/decoders necessary.

The key point was to create a JSON parser, and set the parser name in the INPUT section.

Note that the [tail docs](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/tail#getting_started) say you should set up the DB option. This is just a minimal config to get it working.

`fluent-bit.conf`:

```
[SERVICE]
  Parsers_File parsers.conf

[INPUT]
  Name tail
  Parser myparser
  Path /json_objs_separated_by_newlines.log

[OUTPUT]
  Name es
  Host elasticsearch
  # Required for Elasticsearch 8+
  Suppress_Type_Name On
```

`parsers.conf`:

```
[PARSER]
  Name myparser
  Format json
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the Fluent Bit Nest filter for that purpose, please refer to the following documentation:

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/filter/nest

Comment: OP - "The documentation for Filters and Parsers are really poor and not clear.". I've spent good enough time with the doc hence reason ended up with this question.

Comment: The documentation is EXTREMELY lacking

Comment: Nest is actually the opposite of what's required here, as we want to un-nest