# Fluent-bit - Splitting json

Tags: logging, fluentd, grafana-loki, fluent-bit

I'm sending logs to ES with fluentd. App logs are in JSON format. Here is one of them.
I am using ECS and Grafana.

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2020-12-24T12:16:43.2784Z",
  "level": "INFO",
  "category": "HTTP:Request/Response",
  "data": "{\"HttpMethod\":\"POST\",\"Accept-Encoding : gzip\",\"Cache-Control : max-age=259200\",\"Content-Type : application/json\",\"Content-Length : 569\",\"X-Forwarded-Port : 443\"}",
  "identifier": "4c1d2e8d-7585-4a63-abd6-75b4d2a400de"
}
```

Here is the fluentbit conf that I use

```
[SERVICE]
    parsers_file        parsers.conf
    plugins_file        plugins.conf

[FILTER]
    Name            parser
    Parser          json
    Match           *
    Key_Name        data
    Reserve_Data    on
    Preserve_Key    on
```

I wondering if it is possible to fluentbit so it will store each property individually as below

```
"@timestamp": "2020-12-24T12:16:43.2784Z",
# break the key/value pair and parse the value as json and store each property individually
"HttpMethod": "POST"
"Accept-Encoding": ...
"Cache-Control": ...
"Content-Type": ...
"Content-Length": ...
"X-Forwarded-Port": ...
  "identifier": "4c1d2e8d-7585-4a63-abd6-75b4d2a400de"
```

Currently, in Grafana, it looks like this (sorry I corp it to hide some content):
[image]

PS. It looks like similar to what this OP ([Fluent-bit - Splitting json log into structured fields in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841754/fluent-bit-splitting-json-log-into-structured-fields-in-elasticsearch)) is trying to do but I could not get it to work for myself. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you used tag for Loki? Is loki in use here, and if so, do you expect loki to have parsed json fields as labels too?

Comment: yes, loki is in case here. 
could you pleae guide me what you mean by "tag" in this context?
and yes, the goal is to hope I can have it parse the value in "data" as json and have it list all keys along with others such as "level", and "catagory". thank you!

Comment: By tag in this context I mean [StackOverflow's tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and specifically [tag:grafana-loki].

Comment: Regarding question: Loki advises us against parsing JSON before string it in Loki, and instead parsing it in queries, like this: `{filename="some.json"} | json`. Look [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/get-started/labels/#cardinality) and [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/get-started/labels/bp-labels/#use-dynamic-labels-sparingly).